# import csv file to database in codeIgniter without repetition?

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I import csv file to database ..But If import the same file again the data repetition .. I need to import only the new rows in csv file

example 
first File f1

```
progr   progr               2.22222E+13     eee     xxxxx
```

the second file f2

```
progr   progr               2.22222E+13     eee     xxxxx
progr   progr               2.22222E+13
```

I need if I import f1 then f2

the result is

```
 progr  progr               2.22222E+13     eee     xxxxx
 progr  progr               2.22222E+13
```

but my result

```
 progr  progr               2.22222E+13     eee     xxxxx
 progr  progr               2.22222E+13     eee     xxxxx
 progr  progr               2.22222E+13
```

How can I do that? 
thanks..

Comment: Is it likely that you would end up with 2 or more of the same rows or is there something about them that's unique every time?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier to import all the data first then just manipulate them inside your DB.